# How to delete a range of keys in memcached (using Dalli+RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I am running Ruby on Rails and am using the Dalli gem to access memcached.

Question: how do I delete a range of keys (not multiple, but a range) for something like: delete all memcached entries with a key that begins with "USERINFO", in other words, how can I use wildcards to delete a range of keys?

Comment: don't think memcached supports anything like this

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, no and you don't want to do that.

The `dalli` gem nor `memcached` support deleting multiple keys with a single command out of the box and for good reason. Since memcached determines the location of cached values by hashing the key, in a production environment with multiple cache nodes, a `delete_matched` operation would need to scan across all the nodes looking for keys that potentially match. This defeats a key goal of `memcached` which is performance.

There exist several implementations that extend `dalli` and promise to provide an implementation of `deleted_matched`. These all appear to trade-off programmer convenience over performance so use them with caution. Taking a look at sources of these gems before using them is a good start.

---

Related questions [Is it possible to get/search Memcached keys by a prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889631/is-it-possible-to-get-search-memcached-keys-by-a-prefix)

Answer (score -3):

You should have a look at Rails.cache.delete_matched : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store/delete_matched

Does exactly what you want, theorically :

`Rails.cache.delete_matched /^USERINFO/`

Comment: This method does not work with Dalli (or the standard Memcached cache store in Rails).

Comment: You can try this gem for adding delete_matched functionality to dalli https://github.com/Phobos98/dalli-delete-matched