# Using memcached to throttle connections

Tags: ruby, memcached, rackattack

I'm trying to understand how [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) uses memcached to throttle connections.

As far as I can tell there's no easy way to manage lists in memcached, and no way to [search keys by prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889631/is-it-possible-to-get-search-memcached-keys-by-a-prefix). Yet rack-attack is somehow keeping a list count within cache, but I'm staring at the source code and can't figure out how it works?

https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/lib/rack/attack/throttle.rb
https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/lib/rack/attack/cache.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to emulate namespacing, tagging and indexing with memcached, which allows you to work around many limitations (in your case you could maintain prefixes as tags). [This article](http://dustin.sallings.org/2011/02/17/memcached-set.html) has some good ideas, and [the memcached docs](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks) have some neat tricks too.

Comment: Thanks- I ended up just replacing memcached with redis, which supports  lists natively, instead of trying to mess with these work arounds